# MYSQL Sum of eatch row and limit to the best 15

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I've this table : extended

```
+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-  -+-----+-----+
| Name   |  T1 | T2  | T1  | T3  | .. | T19 | T20 |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-  -+-----+-----+
| john   |  5  | 10  | 50  | 10  | .. | 20  | 8   |
| bill   |  2  | 8   | 11  | 5   | .. | 9   | 55  |
| james  |  30 | 15  | 12  | 40  | .. | 13  | 10  |
| elsie  |  28 | 35  | 20  | 32  | .. | 18  | 1   |
|  ....  |  .. | ..  | ..  | ..  | .. | ..  | ..  |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-  -+-----+-----+
```

And i want to return this one :

```
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-  -+-----+-----+
| Name   | TOTAL |  T1 | T2  | T1  | T3  | .. | T19 | T20 |
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-  -+-----+-----+
| bill   |  250  |  2  | 8   | 11  | 5   | .. | 9   | 55  |
| john   |  230  |  5  | 10  | 50  | 10  | .. | 20  | 8   |
| elsie  |  158  |  28 | 35  | 20  | 32  | .. | 18  | 1   |
| james  |  129  |  30 | 15  | 12  | 40  | .. | 13  | 10  |
|  ....  |  .... | ..  | ..  | ..  | ..  | .. | ..  | ..  |
+--------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

Order by TOTAL. This total is the sum of best of 15 Tx ...

I don't now how to do this.

The table come from a request ( CREATE VIEW ) from another table with a lot of data.

Can you help me ?

At this point, i do the sum of ALL Tx, but it's not what i want ...

```
SELECT `Name`, (T1+T2+ T3+T4+T5+T6+T7+T8+T9+T10+T11+T12+T13+T14+T15+T16+T17+T18+T19+T20) AS TOTAL, T1,T2, T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20
FROM `extended`
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: You want the sum of the largest 15 T columns for each row?

Comment: no, i want the sum of eatch row ( T1 + T2 + Tx ) but only with the best Tx, exclude the five smallest

Comment: @blap . . . Queries like this are such a good argument for storing data in a normalized form.  Each value should be on its own row if they represent the same thing.

Comment: yes, the 15 largest ... sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i've this table, with all value on its own row, but I can't operate properly ... it's wy i create a view of this first table

Comment: This is a horrible schema design. Even getting the best 15 scores will be difficult because you don't have a single field to `ORDER BY`. Please consider creating a schema that uses 1 to MANY holding rows of scores referenced to a user_id. Then you could do **SELECT scores FROM extended ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,15 WHERE user_id = 1**, then sum those up and save it to your **TOTAL** column.

Comment: @blap Number of columns is constant or will it change over time??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to remove the lowest value, that is easy:

```
select name,
       (t1 + . . . + t20) -
        least(t1, . . . , t20)
from table;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have the `nth` function, so getting the second least and others is quite difficult.

If you had the values in separate rows, you could do:

```
select name, sum(t)
from (select en.*,
             if(@name = name, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 1) as rn,
             @name := name
      from extended_norm en cross join
           (select @name := '', @rn := 0) const
      order by name, t desc
     ) en
where rn <= 15
group by name;
```

With your data structure, you'll probably need to write a user-defined function to do what you want.

EDIT:

If you want the list of t's, you can do it two ways.  You can modify the above to include the pivot (this assumes that you have a column called something like `tnumber` to identify which t-value):

```
select name, sum(case when rn <= 15 then t end) as Total,
       max(case when en.tnumber = 1 then t end) as T1,
       max(case when en.tnumber = 2 then t end) as T2,
       . . .
       max(case when en.tnumber = 1 then t end) as T20
from (select en.*,
             if(@name = name, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 1) as rn,
             @name := name
      from extended_norm en cross join
           (select @name := '', @rn := 0) const
      order by name, t desc
     ) en
group by name;
```

Otherwise, take the above query and join it to the denormalized table:

```
select e.*, tt.total
from extended e join
     (the above query) tt
     on e.name = tt.name;
```

Comment: i will try your second example

Comment: Well, how can i merge the two result ? I try an INNER JOIN, but it doesn't work.
I hope to have a table result with , the SUM AND the individual Tx ( all of them )
A mix and your answer and my thirt request

Comment: @blap . . . I don't understand the question -- and it seems unrelated to your original problem here.  Should you ask anther question?

Comment: It's my first problem :) with your request, i've only the SUM, like i wan't, but i need also the list of T ( from the other table )

Comment: Thanks you a lot ! It's look like exactly what i wan't !! I learned a lot from you !

Answer (score 0):

It's awkward but this can also work!

```
select name, sum(t) from 
(select name, t from (
     select  name, t1 as t from extended
     union 
     select  name, t2 as t from extended
      union 
     select  name, t3 as t from extended
      union 
     select  name, t4 as t from extended
      union 
     select  name, t5 as t from extended
      union 
     select  name, t6 as t from extended
       union 
     select  name, t7 as t from extended
       union 
     select  name, t8 as t from extended
       union 
     select  name, t9 as t from extended
       union 
     select  name, t10 as t from extended
       union 
     select  name, t11 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t12 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t13 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t14 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t15 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t16 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t17 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t18 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t19 as t from extended
        union 
     select  name, t20 as t from extended
     ) z
    where name='bill' order by name, t desc limit 0,15);
```

But you have to run the query for each user by replacing `'bill'` by other name